# python giving "IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds"

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, data-science, data-analysis

Below is the code that I used:

```
#Divide data into train and test
p_dt_train, p_dt_test = train_test_split(p_main_df, test_size=0.2)

#Shape #(3485868, 26)
p_dt_train.shape

p_fit_DT = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=2).fit(p_dt_train.iloc[:,0:26], p_dt_train.iloc[:,26])
```

---

But when I am running the above line of of code aka `p_fit_DT`, the following error occurs:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-9bbf02d21cd5> in <module>()
      1 # In[1]:
      2 #Decision tree for regression
----> 3 p_fit_DT = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=2).fit(p_dt_train.iloc[:,0:26], p_dt_train.iloc[:,26])
      4 
      5 #Apply model on test data

D:\My_Work\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1470             except (KeyError, IndexError):
   1471                 pass
-> 1472             return self._getitem_tuple(key)
   1473         else:
   1474             # we by definition only have the 0th axis

D:\My_Work\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _getitem_tuple(self, tup)
   2011     def _getitem_tuple(self, tup):
   2012 
-> 2013         self._has_valid_tuple(tup)
   2014         try:
   2015             return self._getitem_lowerdim(tup)

D:\My_Work\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _has_valid_tuple(self, key)
    220                 raise IndexingError('Too many indexers')
    221             try:
--> 222                 self._validate_key(k, i)
    223             except ValueError:
    224                 raise ValueError("Location based indexing can only have "

D:\My_Work\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _validate_key(self, key, axis)
   1955             return
   1956         elif is_integer(key):
-> 1957             self._validate_integer(key, axis)
   1958         elif isinstance(key, tuple):
   1959             # a tuple should already have been caught by this point

D:\My_Work\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _validate_integer(self, key, axis)
   2007         l = len(ax)
   2008         if key >= l or key < -l:
-> 2009             raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")
   2010 
   2011     def _getitem_tuple(self, tup):

IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

Please guide me as where I am going wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your `DataFrame` is of shape `(3485868, 26)`, then indices along axis 1 will run from 0 to 25 inclusive. So maybe you mean to do:

```
p_fit_DT = \
DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=2).fit(p_dt_train.iloc[:,0:25], 
p_dt_train.iloc[:,25])
```

Might also be clearer if you refactor your code into more steps, like:

```
# Initialise instance for Decision Tree Regression
dtr = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=2)

# Get training inputs and outputs as numpy arrays
X_tr, y_tr = p_dt_train.iloc[:, 0:25].values, p_dt_train.iloc[:, 25].values.reshape((-1, 1))

# Fit model using training data
dtr.fit(X_tr, y_tr)
```

Comment: It worked! Great! Thanks for helping me out. 
First data science project :)

Comment: No probs! Good luck! Feel free to approve my answer or up-vote :)